# How to map a structure from a buffer like in C with a pointer and cast

Tags: node.js

In `C`, I can define many structures and structure of structures.
From a `buffer`, I can just set the pointer at the beginning of this structure to say this buffer represents this structure.

Of course, I do not want to copy anything, just mapping, otherwise I loose the benefit of the speed.

Is it possible in NodeJs ? How can I do ? How can I be sure it's a mapping and not `creating a new object and copy information inside` ?

Example:

```
struct House = {
  uint8 door,
  uint16BE kitchen,
  etc...
}

var mybuff = Buffer.allocate(10, 0)
var MyHouse = new House(mybuff) // same as  `House* MyHouse = (House*) mybuff`
console.log(MyHouse.door) // will display the value of door
console.log(MyHouse.kitchen) // will display the value of kitchen with BE function.
```

This is wrong but explain well what I am looking for.
This without copying anything.

And if I do `MyHouse.door=56`, `mybuff` contains know the 56. I consider `mybuff` as a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit after question update below*

Opposed to C/C++, javascript uses pionters by default, so you don't have to do anything. It's the other way around, actually: You have to put some effort in if you want a *copy* of the current object.

In C, a struct is nothing more than a compile-time reference to different parts of data in the struct. So:

```
struct X {
    int foo;
    int bar;
}
```

is nothing more than saying: if you want bar from a variable with type X, just add the length of foo (length of int) to the base pointer.

In Javascript, we do not even have such a type. We can just say:

```
var x = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2
}
```

The lookup of bar will automatically be a pointer (we call them references in javascript) lookup. Because javascript does not have types, you can view an object as a map/dictionary with pointers to mixed types.

If you, for any reason, want to create a copy of a datastructure, you would have to iterate through the entire datastructure (recursively) and create a copy of the datastructure manually. The basic types are not pointer based. These include number (Javascript automatically differentiates between int and float under the hood), string and boolean.

### Edit after question update

Although I am not an expert on this area, I do not think it is possible. The problem is, the underlying data representation (as in how the data is represented as bytes in memory) is different, because javascript does not have compile-time information about data structures. As I said before, javascript doesn't have classes/structs, just objects with fields, which basically behave (and may be implemented as) maps/dictionaries.

There are, however, some third party libraries to cope with these problems. There are two general approaches:

1. Unpack everything to javascript objects. The data will be copied, but you can work with it as normal javascript objects. You should use this if you read/write the data intensively, because the performance increase you get when working with normal javascript objects outweighs the advantage of not having to unpack the data. [Link to example library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-struct)
2. Leave all data in the buffer. When you need some of the data, compute the location of the data in the buffer *at runtime*, and read/write at this location accordingly. Because the struct data location computations are done in runtime, you should use this only when you have loads of data and only a few reads/writes to it. In this case the performance decrease of unpacking all data outweighs the few runtime computations that have to be done. [Link to example library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/struct)

As a side-note, if the amount of data you have to process isn't that much, I'd recommend to just unpack the data. It saves you the headache of having to use the library as interface to your data. Computers are fast enough nowadays to copy/process some amount of data in memory. Also, these third party libraries are just some examples. I recommend you do a little more research for libraries to decide which one suits your needs.

Comment: But if I already have a buffer, how can I map the structure ? I allocated the buffer from NodeJs and changed it in a `node-ffi` callback. I'd like to access to the different elements quickly without writting `readUInt32LE()` everytime. Im gonna change my question.

Comment: if you do `var x` the buffer/memory area to hold `x` will be allocated, unlike a pointer of `x` you map to a buffer. Only the address size will be allocated.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to accomplish. Why do you want to create a buffer? Why won't you use 'normal' javascript objects and arrays? Can you give some context? I never worked, or had to work with javascript buffers before, so it's possible you are using them purely from your C-background without actually needing them.